# Youtube video sometimes doesn't play on load page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using slick slider for sliding images and videos.

The code that I'm trying is in codepen https://codepen.io/rexhep_r/pen/eYYJeJE

I'm displaying the video in this way

```
<div class="item youtube">
    <iframe class="embed-player slide-media" width="980" height="520" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QV5EXOFcdrQ?enablejsapi=1&controls=0&fs=0&iv_load_policy=3&rel=0&showinfo=0&loop=1&Q&start=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
    <p class="caption">YouTube</p>
  </div>
```

The video should start automatically but sometimes when I make hard reload (or, in mobile) doesn't start playing.

Comment: What browser(s) are you seeing the error with? It works as expected for me in Chrome.

Comment: @ecg8 In chrome, does not always happen. After some hard refreshing. I think that is something with Youtube API, because when it happens, in console I'm having this kind of error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()`